# My Recycler View show items deleted from device Android

Tags: java, android

//My delete onClick

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
   File file = new File(arrayList.get(position).getStr_path());
   file.delete();
   arrayList.remove(position);
   Adapter_VideoFolder.this.arrayList.remove(position);
   Adapter_VideoFolder.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

//My Recycler View show items deleted from device, my code is:

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How can I make the recycler view not show the deleted items?